# How to sort a .bib file with biber?

Tags: biber, sorting

I try to use `biber` (version 2.1) tool mode (`--tool`) to sort my `.bib` file using the standard sorting configuration in the manual, but no matter what I do and no matter how I tweak the sorting specification in `biber.conf`, the `.bib` file is sorted in some unexpected way, or not at all.

Example:

Take the following `.bib` file that is correctly sorted:

```
@article{Addis2008,
  author       = {Addis, Michael E},
  journaltitle = {Clinical Psychology: Science and Practice},
  number       = {3},
  pages        = {153--168},
  title        = {Gender and depression in men},
  volume       = {15},
  year         = {2008},
}

@book{Bruner1990,
  author     = {Jerome Bruner},
  location   = {London},
  publisher  = {Harvard University},
  title      = {Acts of Meaning},
  titleaddon = {The {Jerusalem}--{Harvard} Lectures},
  year       = {1990},
}

@article{Draper2002,
  author       = {Jan Draper},
  journaltitle = {Sociology of Health \& Illness},
  number       = {6},
  pages        = {771--795},
  subtitle     = {The Ultrasound Scan, Fathers and the Power of Visual Knowledge},
  title        = {'It Was a Real Good Show'},
  volume       = {24},
  year         = {2002},
}
```

Running `biber --tool` on the above file using the following configuration (from the manual):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sorting>
        <presort>mm</presort>
        <sort order="1">
            <sortitem order="1">presort</sortitem>
        </sort>
        <sort order="2" final="1">
            <sortitem order="1">sortkey</sortitem>
        </sort>
        <sort order="3">
            <sortitem order="1">sortname</sortitem>
            <sortitem order="2">author</sortitem>
            <sortitem order="3">editor</sortitem>
            <sortitem order="4">translator</sortitem>
            <sortitem order="5">sorttitle</sortitem>
            <sortitem order="6">title</sortitem>
        </sort>
        <sort order="4">
            <sortitem order="1">sortyear</sortitem>
            <sortitem order="2">year</sortitem>
        </sort>
        <sort order="5">
            <sortitem order="1">sorttitle</sortitem>
            <sortitem order="2">title</sortitem>
        </sort>
        <sort order="6">
            <sortitem order="1" pad_side="left" pad_width="4" pad_char="0">volume</sortitem>
            <sortitem order="2">0000</sortitem>
        </sort>
    </sorting>
</config>
```

This should, as far as I understand, end up with a `.bib` file sorted on author as first key (sort order 3 above). Instead, it yields the following order:

1. Bruner
2. Addis
3. Draper

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand how you are getting that order. I just tried your example and it works fine for me. With no biber.conf, the order is unchanged from the source.bib, which is expected (as the default biber-tool.conf has "citeorder" sorting) and with your example biber.conf in the same directory as the .bib file, I get Addis, Bruner, Draper order in the output .bib. Your result is very strange - it's neither the default sorting nor the config file sorting. Biber tells you which config file it's using when you run it - perhaps you have some other config file somewhere?

Comment: This was a bug that you now have fixed. I think I reported it by email, so it never went through the github issue tracker. The question is obsolete. Merry Christmas! ;-)

Comment: could you post a sample command-line on how you run this? I tried to specify the config file (which is then also mentioned by the biber output), but it still uses the sorting schema `none` and my bib file is not sorted.

Comment: I ended up writing my own BibTeX parser in perl (based on BibTeX::Parser) so I really don't remember. Perhaps I had to add the locale in `LANG` environment variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update biber. This was a bug in biber 2.1. Since version 2.2, sorting works as expected and the above example is correctly sorted.